# CodeLite: relative paths in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, relative-path, codelite

Codelite puts absolute paths in makefile, such as:

```
=== mygreatapp.workspace ===
<...>
WorkspacePath          := "/home/vladon/Projects/mygreatapp"
ProjectPath            := "/home/vladon/Projects/mygreatapp"
<...>
===
```

And in generated makefiles it uses absolute paths also.

Therefore app cannot be build on other machine.

How to make paths relative in makefiles produced by CodeLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I find a simple solution:

```
codelite-make -w <workspace-file> -c <configuration>
```

It regenerates `Makefile` with current directories on the target machine. Running it before `make` solves the problem.

Comment: This solution needs codelite on the target machine, which does not seem generally acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

In workspace and project, Codelite uses relative paths. Codelite generates Makefile during the build (and the generated Makefile does have not the purpose to be distributed, see them as temporary files as the .o generated).

So you may build on other machine using Codelite directly.

If you want a makefile generator, there are specific tools for that.

Comment: What is those specific tools?

Comment: @vladon: autoconf, CMake, premake, ... (and the last 2 can also create Codelite project).